# How to change color of a column based on a field's value in Odoo12?

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo, odoo-12

I have inherited a tree view and added a selection field to this view. I need to have different colors based on the value of the field. I want to know, is it possible in Odoo 12 to have values of a column with different colors or not. I have tried blew code but it does not work in my case.

python code:

```
availability = fields.Selection(string="Availability", compute='_compute_physician_availability', selection=[('available', "Available"), ('not_available', "Not Available")])

def _compute_physician_availability(self):
        for physician in self:
            employees = self.env['hr.employee'].search([('user_id', '=', physician.user_id.id)])
            for employee in employees:
                if employee.attendance_state == 'checked_in':
                    physician.availability = 'available'
                else:
                    physician.availability = 'not_available'
```

XML code:

```
<record id="physician_tree_view_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Physician Tree View Inherited</field>
        <field name="model">hms.physician</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="acs_hms.view_physician_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='email']" position="after">
                <field name="availability" options="{'color': 'red: availability == Not Available'}"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

I have also tried below code, but it also does not worked in my case.

```
 <field name="availability" colors=="red:availability=='not_available'; green:availability=='available'"/>
```

I need to have different colors for each state of my physician for more user-friendliness of my tree view and it is a requirement by the client.

Answer (score 1):

Odoo 9th and odoo 10th version support custom colors in tree view but Odoo 11th and odoo 12th version support decorators only.

The possible decorators are:

```
decoration-bf - shows the line in BOLD 
decoration-it - shows the line in ITALICS 
decoration-danger - shows the line in LIGHT RED 
decoration-info - shows the line in LIGHT BLUE 
decoration-muted - shows the line in LIGHT GRAY 
decoration-primary - shows the line in LIGHT PURPLE 
decoration-success - shows the line in LIGHT GREEN 
decoration-warning - shows the line in LIGHT BROWN
```

Example

```
<record id="physician_tree_view_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Physician Tree View Inherited</field>
    <field name="model">hms.physician</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="acs_hms.view_physician_tree"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//tree" position="attributes">
            <attribute name='decoration-danger'>availability='not_available'</attribute>
            <attribute name='decoration-success'>availability='available'</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: It works and changes the whole record text color upon the condition's match, but what if we want to do this (change the text color) of one column? Is it possible to do it? I searched a lot for it and found below module and tried to use it my case, but it did not work on my case. https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/12.0/web_tree_dynamic_colored_field/

Comment: @IbrahimRahimi, by default in Odoo with condition you can change color of one record not only one column.
Yes you can try application

Comment: @MitalVaghani, Then how can I do it? I have tested a couple of solutions but none of them worked in my case.